# How to dynamically declare variables in a loop?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a program in which an object is declared every time a loop is passed through.

```
package sequence;

public class SequenceServer {
    SequenceObj sequence = new SequenceObj();
    public void findSequence(int[] sequence, int lastNumber) {
        for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
            SequenceObj sequenceTemp = new SequenceObj(); // this line is wrong, but I don't know how to make it work
        }
    }
}
```

There are no errors, but I need to make it so a potentially infinite number of variables can be declared through the user interacting with the program, as opposed to me individually declaring all of the variables.

Comment: You probably need some sort of Collection. It is absolutely unclear what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: use a `List` or a `Set`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     `public class SequenceServer {
             SequenceObj sequence;
             public void findSequence(int[] sequence, int lastNumber) {
                      for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++) {
                              sequence = new SequenceObj(); // this line is wrong, 
                         // but I don't know how to make it work
                      }
              }
         }`
```